# Lost then re-found phone

Tags: factory-reset, lg-g3

I lost my android, and while it was lost I did the factory reset from the device manager through google.  Since then, the phone has been found.  In the off chance that the factory reset did not go through, as the phone was offline or dead,is there any way I can undo this? Also, how annoying or difficult is it to re upload apps, music, etc after the factory reset?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it easily.

First Make sure you didn't have any Sim Card inserted in your phone and go away from any possible wifi area *(incase if you did turned on Wifi or Mobile Data)*.

Then simply remove your **Google account** through Android Settings and try to use another Google account. (this works for all case)

This can help you to get your phone being formatted.

Comment: does this mean that from now on, I will have to use the new google account on my phone?

Comment: basically yes. Google Didn't provided any help on that. To Minimize the risk, that will be the best option. Wait, Let me explore more in Help File of Android Device Manager.

Comment: I did explored all help files (it wasn't too vast enough, just 3 files) and there anre nothing mentioned about that.

Comment: Alright thank you! If I cannot avoid the factory reset on my LG G3, will this impact the phone negatively aside from deleting any downloaded apps, contacts, messages, etc?

Comment: You can first backup all your stuff while your original Google account is removed (see our [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info) for "ADB backups" and the questions linked at its end) – and also "dis-associate" the device from your account (via the Google Web interface, unauthorize it). Having everything backed up, setup your Google account again. If it now performs a factory-reset (which it *might* not, due to being disassociated/de-authorized), you can restore your data.

Comment: Damage on phone is negligible but you can backup the apps and other contents (be sure not to get connected to internet before it) and then the loss and damage will be zero except your couple of hours :D